# <img> element does not respect flow and is rendered in an unexpected position in the browser

Tags: html, css, image

I'm just starting to learn HTML and CSS and I ran into this mystery.
In my HTML file, the flow indicates that my `<img>` should be rendered on the webpage BELOW the `<p>` element of class "lorem".
However, you can see in the screenshot below that it appears somewhere in the middle of the screen.

[This is a screenshot of how my problem looks in the browser.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWjDM.png)

All the code I've written is purely to test out things for myself, so I realize it can look ridiculous for anyone else. :)

Thank you!

```css
.rectangle {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid seagreen;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 20px;
}

img {
    width: 300px;
    background-color: blueviolet;
    padding: 50px;
}

.lorem{
    border: 1px solid red;
    background-color: aqua;
    padding: 40px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
 <p>Even though I am writing all of this on a single line, <h1>this bit here should appear on a separate line.</h1>Did it work?</p>

        <div class="rectangle">
            <p>I’m a rectangle!</p>
        </div>

        <div class="rectangle">
            <p>So am I!</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="rectangle">
            <p>Me three!</p>
        </div>

        <img src="./background.jpg" alt="background">

        <p class="lorem">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
```

Comment: You can't put h1 inside a paragraph

Comment: Read up on the CSS [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) property

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Is this what you wanted?**

```css
body{
  font-family:'Work Sans',sans-serif;
  line-height:1.5;
  text-align:center;
}

.rectangle {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid seagreen;
  text-align:center;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 1rem;
}

.rectangle:first-child{
  margin-left:0;
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
}

img {
  background-color: lightcoral;
  padding: 2.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  
}

.lorem {
  border: 1px solid pink;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  padding: 40px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p>Even though I am writing all of this on a single line,
    <h1>this bit here should appear on a separate line.</h1>Did it work?</p>

  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="rectangle">
      <p>I’m a rectangle!</p>
    </div>

    <div class="rectangle">
      <p>So am I!</p>
    </div>

    <div class="rectangle">
      <p>Me three!</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <img src="./background.jpg" alt="background">

  <p class="lorem">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>


</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't put a title in a paragraph. If you want it big and bold, you can stlye it with css. I know its just practice, but semantics are quite important.

Comment: IMG elements are inline, meaning that unless they are floated they will flow horizontally with text and other inline elements. They are "block" elements in that they have a width and a height. But they behave more like "inline-block" in that respect.   The divs you made inline-block, so thats why they all apear one after the other.  It is actually after the rectangle class divs, just because of the padding appears higher